# Have an issue with box-shadow Inset bottom only

Tags: css

I am using box-shadow to create an inner shadow...

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
```

...but would like the inner shadow to come in from the bottom only. I have tried several ways of trying to make this work but can't... How would I do this with box-shadow?

Comment: how about this one `inset 0px -10px 6px #555555;`?

Comment: Didn't really work for me. ACJ nailed it

Comment: For another type of solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428355/7910454.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use a negative value for the fourth length which defines the spread distance. This is often overlooked, but supported by all major browsers. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acjbizar/rM5tB/1194/) for the result.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You’re welcome. It is documented (to an extend) here: [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow).

Comment: `box-shadow` should be after `-webkti-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`

Comment: Agreed, @ShlomiHassid. I edited both the snippets to reflect this.

Comment: Not working on firefox nightly (Oct 20, 2015)
http://postimg.org/image/3yq7nasih/

Comment: Works just fine for me, @Jakob Abfalter. Do note that different user agents have different rounding mechanisms, causing specific settings not to be visible/notable in specific contexts.

Answer (score 23):

[JSnippet DEMO](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/246/boxshadow-Inset-one-side-only)

**On top only:**

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
 box-shadow:        inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
```

**On bottom only:**

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
 box-shadow:        inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
```

**On top and bottom only:**

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                    inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                    inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
 box-shadow:        inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                    inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
```

**Quick Example**

```css
.shadow-top {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
     box-shadow:        inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey;
}
.shadow-bottom {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
     box-shadow:        inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
}
.shadow-top-bottom {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                        inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                        inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
     box-shadow:        inset  0  10px 10px -10px grey, 
                        inset  0 -10px 10px -10px grey;
}

div { display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; width:150px; height:100px; background:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class='shadow-top'></div>
<div class='shadow-bottom'></div>
<div class='shadow-top-bottom'></div>
```