# How to create a inset box-shadow only on one side?

Tags: css

Is it possible to somehow only have inset box-shadow on one side of a div ? Note that I'm talking about an **inset** box-shadow here, not the normal outer box-shadow.

For example, in the following JSFiddle, you'll see that the inset shadow appears on all 4 sides, in varying degrees.

How do I get it to ONLY show at the top ? Or at most ONLY at top and bottom ?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/KFrun/

```css
.box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 1px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 1px #000000;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An alternate (and fully customizable) way would be a background gradient ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get box-shadow on left & right sides only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997032/how-to-get-box-shadow-on-left-right-sides-only)

Answer (score 317):

This is what you are looking for. It has examples for each side you want with a shadow.

```css
.top-box
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.left-box
{
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.right-box
{
    box-shadow: inset -7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.bottom-box
{
    box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

See the snippet for more examples:

```css
body {
    background-color:#0074D9;
}
div {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.top-box {
    box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.left-box {
    box-shadow: inset 7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.right-box {
    box-shadow: inset -7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.bottom-box {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.top-gradient-box {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999 0, #ffffff 7px, #ffffff 100%);
}
.left-gradient-box {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #999 0, #ffffff 7px, #ffffff 100%);
}
.right-gradient-box {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #999 0, #ffffff 7px, #ffffff 100%);
}
.bottom-gradient-box {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #999 0, #ffffff 7px, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
        This area has a top shadow using box-shadow
</div>

<div class="left-box">
        This area has a left shadow using box-shadow
</div>

<div class="right-box">
        This area has a right shadow using box-shadow
</div>

<div class="bottom-box">
        This area has a bottom shadow using box-shadow
</div>

<div class="top-gradient-box">
        This area has a top shadow using gradients
</div>
<div class="left-gradient-box">
        This area has a left shadow using gradients
</div>
<div class="right-gradient-box">
        This area has a right shadow using gradients
</div>
<div class="bottom-gradient-box">
        This area has a bottom shadow using gradients
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, however, it still causes the shadow to appear along other edges. Solution: make the spread radius (the param just before the colour) even smaller, lower, e.g. (the top-box): 
`box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);`

Comment: @ellockie No, that actually decreases the shadow showing from the top too.

Answer (score 14):

The trick is a second `.box-inner` inside, which is larger in width than the original `.box`, and the `box-shadow` is applied to that.

Then, added more padding to the `.text` to make up for the added width.

## This is how the logic looks:

[image: box logic]

## And here's how it's done in CSS:

Use max width for `.inner-box` to not cause `.box` to get wider, and `overflow` to make sure the remaining is clipped:

```
.box {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

110% is wider than the parent which is 100% in a child's context (should be the same when the parent `.box` has a fixed width, for example).
    Negative margins make up for the width and cause the element to be centered (instead of only the right part hiding):

```
.box-inner {
    width: 110%;
    margin-left:-5%;
    margin-right: -5%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 1px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 1px #000000;
}
```

And add some padding on the X axis to make up for the wider `.inner-box`:

```
.text {
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

## [Here's a working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KFrun/6/)

If you inspect the Fiddle, you'll see:

[image: .box]
[image: .box-inner]
[image: .text]

Comment: How can you just post the link to fiddle without the code? :O

Comment: Man! That's a SO hack! Cool :P

Comment: In my Firefox I can't see the text at the right and left border. The text is simply cut off. (Here is screen shot http://goo.gl/aO8ZX) I have try it myself and used some extra `div` to hide the shadow... http://jsfiddle.net/KFrun/19

Comment: Yes i use jsfiddle.net/KFrun/6/
Is it possibly some Firefox version problem?
I use the Firefox 21.0 for Ubuntu...

Comment: But there is still a shadow underneath

Comment: You can apply the same 110% logic to the height, effectively hiding the bottom as well.

Answer (score 14):

Quite a bit late, but a duplicate answer that doesn't require altering the padding or adding extra divs can be found here: [Have an issue with box-shadow Inset bottom only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081814/have-an-issue-with-box-shadow-inset-bottom-only).  It says, "Use a negative value for the fourth length which defines the spread distance. This is often overlooked, but supported by all major browsers"

From the answerer's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM5tB/2/):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #000000;
```

Answer (score 9):

This comes a little close.

```
.box
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 10px 5px -3px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 10px 5px -3px #000000;
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried! But he didn't wanted that so didn't posted it as the answer! :(

Comment: Big Like. Thank You ❤️

Comment: There can be a simplest answer than this one (at least for the moment). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the exact thing you are looking for, but you can create a very similar effect by using `rgba` in combination with [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%);
```

This creates a linear-gradient from black with 50% opacity (`rgba(0,0,0,.5)`) to transparent (`rgba(0,0,0,0)`) which starts being competently transparent 30% from the top. You can play with those values to create your desired effect. You can have it on a different side by adding a deg-value (`linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%)`) or switching the colors around. If you want really complex shadows like different angles on different sides you could even start layering `linear-gradient`.

Here is a snippet to see it in action:

```css
.box {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%);
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try it, maybe useful...

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(255,255,255), 0 7px 3px #cbc9c9;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(255,255,255), 0 7px 5px #cbc9c9;
                    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(255,255,255), 0 7px 5px #cbc9c9;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgb(255,255,255), 0 7px 5px #cbc9c9;
```

above `CSS` cause you have a box shadow in bottom.
you can red more [Here](http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/09/css3-spread-value-and-box-shadow-on-one-side-only/)

Answer (score 1):

Setting all four at once is easy with the normal box-shadow. Setting 1 is easy using the negative spread, but you can do two or three sides easily enough (without adding divs) by leveraging pseudo elements like so:

```css
.box-example {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 9px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px dashed grey;
    position: relative;
}
.box-example::after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -7px 9px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
}
.box-example2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 9px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px dashed grey;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.box-example2::before,
.box-example2::after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -7px 9px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
}
.box-example2::after {
    box-shadow: inset -7px 0px 9px -7px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-example">I have a top and bottom</div>
<div class="box-example2">I have a top, bottom, and right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inset Box Shadow only on Top side?

```
#box {
            background: #CCC;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            font: bold 18px/1.2em sans-serif;
            height: auto;
            margin: 15px auto;
            padding: 75px 15px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 80%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally you can't do such a thing, but you should try this CSS trick:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 3vw 6vw rgba(0,0,0,0.6), inset 0 -3vw 6vw rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the simplest way:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 calc(7px + 42px) 0 -42px black;
```

Of course, you can omit the `calc()` part and set `49px` instead; it's only there for clarity and/or DRY (e.g. by using custom vars).

> The third [blur] field is set to zero to avoid confusion; feel free to put any value there.