# How can i make this effect in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to know how can I make this effect:

[image: white-shadow].

That white shadow on right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inset Box Shadow only on one side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572619/inset-box-shadow-only-on-one-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-shadow` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Here's an example for the desired effect:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is done with the `box-shadow` property. You can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp).

```css
.example {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```