# CSS right side of div curved (example image provided)

Tags: css

I am trying to do this with CSS on a div (not an image just a div with a background colour):

[image: See the right side of the div ... that's what I need]

If you see the example image above and look on the right, that's what I need to do, without an image.

How can I do this with css?

Comment: Try using an inner shadow in the box-shadow property. Does that serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a box shadow with an inset seems to achieve this (it is widely supported by most browsers: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_box-shadow_inset). You can also add border-top-right-radius and border-bottom-right-radius to give the corners a curve too.

```css
.grey-box {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px
}

.right-curve-shadow {
    box-shadow: inset -20px 0 15px -15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.right-side-radius {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-box right-curve-shadow right-side-radius">
</div>
```

You can play around with the colour ( rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5) to another value ) and also with the offsets / spread of the box shadow.

See here for more information:
[How to create a inset box-shadow only on one side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572619/how-to-create-a-inset-box-shadow-only-on-one-side)